How to properly filter out parts of the map where raster values are outside of given range in geoserver with isolines and labels?
I have the following configuration of layers in geoserver layer group all based on netcdf
SalinityData with style salinity - providing basic colormap for styling raster
SalinityData with style salinity-contour - contains transformation raster->contour lines + LineSymbolizer (drawing isolines) + TextSymbolizer (putting also label along contour lines)
SalinityData with style filter - takes low and high thresholds from ENV and creates mask where values from the raster is inside specified length and applying it as destination-in
See style definitions below
all of this actually works pretty well besides isolines labels being still visible where underlying color and lines being filtered out.
result:

salinity style:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld
http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" version="1.0.0">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>salinity</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>A raster style</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <RasterSymbolizer>
            <ColorMap>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#00168B" quantity="25" opacity="0.5" label="25"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#0057FF" quantity="32.0" opacity="0.5" label="32.0"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#00A3FF" quantity="32.5" opacity="0.5" label="32.5"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#44E9FF" quantity="33.0" opacity="0.5" label="33.0"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#44FFC7" quantity="33.5" opacity="0.5" label="33.5"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#B8FF44" quantity="34.0" opacity="0.5" label="34.0"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#FFF61E" quantity="34.5" opacity="0.5" label="34.5"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#FFB800" quantity="34.8" opacity="0.5" label="34.8"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#FF8A00" quantity="34.9" opacity="0.5" label="34.9"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#FF6B00" quantity="35.0" opacity="0.5" label="35.0"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#FF5823" quantity="35.1" opacity="0.5" label="35.1"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#FF450A" quantity="35.2" opacity="0.5" label="35.2"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#CF3200" quantity="40" opacity="0.5" label="40"/>
            </ColorMap>
          </RasterSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>


salinity contour style:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld
http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" version="1.0.0">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>contour</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>Contour</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Transformation>
          <ogc:Function name="ras:Contour">
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>data</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>levels</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>25</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>32</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>32.5</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>33</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>33.5</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>34</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>34.5</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>34.8</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>34.9</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>35</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>35.1</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>35.2</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>40</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
          </ogc:Function>
        </Transformation>
        <Rule>
          <Name>rule1</Name>
          <Title>Contour Line</Title>
          <LineSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#3A3A3A</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-opacity">0.2</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </LineSymbolizer>
          <TextSymbolizer>
            <Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
            </Label>
            <Font>
              <CssParameter name="font-family">Inter</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-style">Normal</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-size">8</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="opacity">0.6</CssParameter>
            </Font>
            <LabelPlacement>
              <LinePlacement/>
            </LabelPlacement>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
            <Priority>2000</Priority>
            <VendorOption name="followLine">true</VendorOption>
            <VendorOption name="repeat">100</VendorOption>
            <VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">50</VendorOption>
            <VendorOption name="maxAngleDelta">30</VendorOption>
          </TextSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>

filter style:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld
http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" version="1.0.0">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>contour</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>Contour</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Transformation>
          <ogc:Function name="ras:RangeLookup">
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>coverage</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>ranges</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Function name="Concatenate">
                <ogc:Literal>[</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Function name="env">
                  <ogc:Literal>low</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>-100</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:Function>
                <ogc:Literal>;</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Function name="env">
                  <ogc:Literal>low</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>-100</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:Function>
                <ogc:Literal>]</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:Function>
              <ogc:Function name="Concatenate">
                <ogc:Literal>[</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Function name="env">
                  <ogc:Literal>low</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>-100</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:Function>
                <ogc:Literal>;</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Function name="env">
                  <ogc:Literal>high</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>250</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:Function>
                <ogc:Literal>]</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:Function>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>outputPixelValues</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>noData</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-250</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
          </ogc:Function>
        </Transformation>
        <Rule>
          <Name>rule1</Name>
          <Title>Mask</Title>
          <RasterSymbolizer>
            <Opacity>1</Opacity>
          </RasterSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
        <VendorOption name="composite">destination-in</VendorOption>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>



If you don't want the labels to show up then you need to filter them in the same way as the raster (and I think you are working through your Rules in the wrong order which is why your contours don't show up).

so I need to add ras:RangeLookup transformation before ras:Contour on my salinity-contour style? Did I get you right?

yes, that sounds likely

cool. Thanks!  I'll try and update. Do you maybe want to put it as the answer so I can accept it?

If you wan to limit where your contours and labels show up then you will need to apply the same filter to them as you do to the raster.

I ended up writing a plugin to register a process to be able to filter. As from the available processes I haven't found which is doing clear filtration.  But core idea is consistent with this answer. Filter underlying coverage data same way for all layers
